# Error: vmaster hook already present before cdev!

Tags: linux-kernel, audio, kernel-modules

### The question

I would like to know how to prevent the following error to appear at my log:

```
snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: vmaster hook already present before cdev!
```

From the code I presume that it has to do with the mute LED indication ("Create a LED classdev and enable as vmaster mute LED"), which is not critical in the working of sound card, but still nice to know that something has been muted.

What is the difference between `cdev` and `vmaster`? Why it matters that vmaster hook is already present? How to configure the `snd_hda_codec_generic` to prevent this error form appearing?

### The research

I know why it happens - because the condition `if (spec->vmaster_mute.hook)` is satisfied.

I have found out [the condition](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/sound/pci/hda/hda_generic.c#L3974) in the source code which triggers the error.  It appears that the `vmaster` flag has been setup within [this code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/86286e486cbdd68f01d330409307f6a6efcd4298/sound/pci/hda/hda_generic.h#L223).

### The system details

`sudo journalctl -xb | grep snd` (*Note:* here you can see the error message)

```
Dec 20 09:19:13 magnetron kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
Dec 20 09:19:13 magnetron kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Dec 20 09:19:13 magnetron kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
Dec 20 09:19:14 magnetron kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: CX8200: BIOS auto-probing.
Dec 20 09:19:14 magnetron kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: vmaster hook already present before cdev!
Dec 20 09:19:14 magnetron kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for CX8200: line_outs=1 (0x16/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
Dec 20 09:19:14 magnetron kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
Dec 20 09:19:14 magnetron kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1d/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
Dec 20 09:19:14 magnetron kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
Dec 20 09:19:14 magnetron kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
Dec 20 09:19:14 magnetron kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
Dec 20 09:19:14 magnetron kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x1a
```

`$lspci -v`:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 140, IOMMU group 9
        Memory at 1ff3018000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at 1ff3000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

`$lshw`:

```
 *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             logical name: card0
             logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D2
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D10p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D9p
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
             resources: iomemory:1f0-1ef iomemory:1f0-1ef irq:140 memory:1ff3018000-1ff301bfff memory:1ff3000000-1ff300ffff
           *-input:0
                product: HDA Digital PCBeep
                physical id: 0
                logical name: input39
                logical name: /dev/input/event20
                capabilities: pci
           *-input:1
                product: HDA Intel PCH Mic
                physical id: 1
                logical name: input40
                logical name: /dev/input/event21
           *-input:2
                product: HDA Intel PCH Line
                physical id: 2
                logical name: input41
                logical name: /dev/input/event22
           *-input:3
                product: HDA Intel PCH Dock Line Out
                physical id: 3
                logical name: input42
                logical name: /dev/input/event23
           *-input:4
                product: HDA Intel PCH Headphone
                physical id: 4
                logical name: input43
                logical name: /dev/input/event24
           *-input:5
                product: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
                physical id: 5
                logical name: input44
                logical name: /dev/input/event25
           *-input:6
                product: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
                physical id: 6
                logical name: input45
                logical name: /dev/input/event26
           *-input:7
                product: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
                physical id: 7
                logical name: input46
                logical name: /dev/input/event27
           *-input:8
                product: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9
                physical id: 8
                logical name: input47
                logical name: /dev/input/event28
           *-input:9
                product: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10
                physical id: 9
                logical name: input48
                logical name: /dev/input/event29
```

The kernel modules loaded: `sudo lsmod | grep snd`

```
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
snd_seq                90112  7 snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_soc_skl           184320  0
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       40960  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_dsp        40960  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     81920  1
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    73728  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_soc_skl
snd_ctl_led            24576  0
snd_hda_codec_conexant    28672  1
snd_soc_core          348160  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          57344  1
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_skl
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         184320  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core          122880  8 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               159744  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              49152  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
snd                   126976  17 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
```

The kernel version:

`uname -a`

```
Linux XXX 6.0.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.0.12-1 (2022-12-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I'm also seeing this on my machine, with kernel 5.15.108

Comment: I also see this on kernel 5.15.108-1-MANJARO

Comment: @Mr.rk you should upvote the question as that shows this is wanted answer.  Thank you.